# Assigning unique tag to list item in a list

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter

I need help with setting tags in my viewHolder object. I have a list that is longer than the screen (on a phone) and i need to set a different tag for each view. As you can see in my preview app (link below)in the exterior fragment that the first item and last item are binded together. I dont' want that, i want every views to be unique. How can I do that.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2xlu23GjnfvTEgtbkprOThtMmM/edit?usp=sharing

thanks

my InspectionListAdapter

```
public class InspectionListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] inspectionTitles;
private final String[] description;

public InspectionListAdapter(Activity context, String[] inspectionTitles,
        String[] description) {
    super(context, R.layout.inspection_item_layout, inspectionTitles);
    this.context = context;
    this.inspectionTitles = inspectionTitles;
    this.description = description;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView, expandButton;
    public TextView txtTitle;
    public TextView txtDescription;
    public RelativeLayout expandLayout;
    public EditText ownDesc, estCost;
    public LayerDrawable listItem;
    public GradientDrawable color;
    public CheckBox checkRepair, checkDone;
    public RelativeLayout mainLayout;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    View rowView = view;

    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inspection_item_layout, null,
                true);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();



        viewHolder.mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.item_layout_main);

        viewHolder.txtTitle = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewItemTitle);

        viewHolder.txtDescription = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewTip);

        viewHolder.listItem = (LayerDrawable) rowView.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.layer_car_background);

        viewHolder.color = (GradientDrawable) (viewHolder.listItem
                .findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.item_list_background));

        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageViewItem);

        viewHolder.expandButton = (ImageView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageViewTitle);

        viewHolder.ownDesc = (EditText) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextDescription);

        viewHolder.estCost = (EditText) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextEstCost);

        viewHolder.checkRepair = (CheckBox) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

        viewHolder.checkDone = (CheckBox) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        viewHolder.checkRepair
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view,
                            boolean arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        if (view.isChecked()) {
                            viewHolder.checkDone.setChecked(false);
                        }
                    }
                });
        viewHolder.checkDone
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view,
                            boolean arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        if (view.isChecked()) {
                            viewHolder.checkRepair.setChecked(false);

                        }
                    }
                });

        viewHolder.expandLayout = (RelativeLayout) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutExpandable);

        viewHolder.expandLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        viewHolder.expandButton
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        if (viewHolder.expandLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                            viewHolder.expandButton
                                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_expand);
                            viewHolder.expandLayout
                                    .setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            if (viewHolder.checkDone.isChecked()) {

                                viewHolder.mainLayout
                                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layer_car_background_green);

                            }
                            if (viewHolder.checkRepair.isChecked()) {

                                viewHolder.mainLayout
                                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layer_car_background_red);
                            }

                        } else {
                            viewHolder.expandButton
                                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_collapse);
                            viewHolder.expandLayout
                                    .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            viewHolder.mainLayout
                                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layer_car_background);

                        }
                    }
                });


        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }


    viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(inspectionTitles[position]);
    viewHolder.txtDescription.setText("Tip: \n" + description[position]);
    viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    viewHolder.expandButton
            .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_expand);

    return rowView;
}
```

}

Comment: I recommend you to learn how the getView works. The views will get recycled. And you shouldn't make "every view unique"

Comment: my list is not a dynamic list, it's a pre-set list generated by a string-array in my string.xml files. I want all my views to retain
their onClickListeners and onCheckChangedListeners

Comment: Please explain where you are trying to set a different tag for each view. What i see is that you set a view holder as tag for views. In which way are they different? And what has 'retaining on click listeners and so' to do with this all? And of course there are more items then fit on the screen. And your google document is unreadable on my tablet so i don't know what is wrong there.

Comment: it's an .apk you should be able to install it and view what my problem is. When you go to the second fragment (this list is longer than the others). If you click on the expand button of the first item, the last item in the list get expanded too, also if you check either of the two checkboxes, the colors change for the last item in the list too...

Comment: Don't understand what you mean with the second fragment. I only get a list when i click the + in the circle. If i then expand Basement Humidity others are not expanded. Also when i check something only it's parent is colored. The unexpanded list does not fill the screen. Testet on two devices.

Comment: If you switch tabs to exterior tab that's where the problem is. The other tabs are fine since there are not recycled because there is not enough item.

Comment: There are no tabs. Just a Summary menu with three items: Repairs To Do, Repairs Done and Summary. They all do nothing. Only the described + does something. I think you posted a different .apk from the one you have in mind.

Comment: Hmmm.. I see INTERIOR and EXTERIOR. But EXTERIOR stays disabled. No other tabs. Probably because only portrait mode is possible? Why such a restriction?

Comment: Arrrghh.. well i can confirm your complaints. This indeed has to do with recycling. Apparently you overlook something in your adapter. Now i can start looking at it. My compliments for the nice layout and the disign of your expandable list item. If you could post some more on google drive i could investigate the test project for your problem. That would be less work for me.

Comment: here's the project (so far)...
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2xlu23GjnfvbWx3X1VHU0hvZDA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I just posted an answer. Please try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is in the onClick of the OnClickListener for viewHolder.expandbutton. There you start immedeately with 'if (viewHolder.....)`. But that is the wrong viewHolder as at the moment the user clicks the view many viewHolders may have been created and died. So you have to obtain the right viewHolder first. something like (untested)

```
                View rowView = (View)v.getParent();

                ViewHolder viewHolder =(ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
```

You put it IN the onClick() method. `final ViewHolder viewHolder;` You made it final in order to use it in onClick() and onCheckedChanged. Remove the final. Unfortunately the getParent() does not work in onCheckedChanged. So we do it different.

```
    viewHolder.checkDone.setTag(viewHolder.checkRepair);
    viewHolder.checkDone
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view,
                        boolean arg1) {

                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)view.getTag();

                    if (view.isChecked()) {
                        //viewHolder.checkRepair.setChecked(false);
                        checkBox.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Do the same for the other checkbox.

Now the color expands over another view. The reason is that you should set the default color at the same time as you set new txtTitle, txtDescription and so on. So add there `viewHolder.mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layer_car_background);`.

For the rest your code misses keeping state. If an item is expanded and the user scrolls the list up and down (i added much more items to be able to scroll more) then the expanded state vanishes. Also checkboxes don't stay checked and color vanishes (add much more items to see). You should add some boolean arrrays (at least three) in which you keep the state. Update those arrays in the events. In getView() read the arrays and put colors and checkboxes checked accordingly. It is not much work to add those arrays you will see...

Comment: Great job ! thanks a lot ! now i'll bang my head with states !